# Turning a spark dataframe of edges into a graphx graph

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have a dataframe as so:

```
> |Id1 |Id2 |attr1 |attr2 |attr3| 
>  ----:----:------:------:-----: 
> |1   |2   |1     |0     |.5   | 
> |1   |3   |1     |1     |.33  | 
> |2   |3   |0     |.6    |.7   |
```

I want to create edges for the nonzero attributes with weights of the values in the table?
How would I go about doing that?  I cant seem to find any easy way so right now I'm just using a for loop and iterating through each row but that seems inefficient.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three attribute columns can be [stacked](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#stack). After filtering the resulting column for nonzero values a [GraphFrame](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/api/python/graphframes.html#graphframes.GraphFrame) can be constructed that has no edges with a zero weight:

```python
df = ...
edges = df.withColumn("weight", F.expr("stack(3,cast(attr1 as double),cast(attr2 as double),cast(attr3 as double))"))\
      .drop("attr1","attr2","attr3") \
      .filter("weight <> 0.0") \
      .withColumnRenamed("Id1", "src") \
      .withColumnRenamed("Id2", "dst")

vertices = edges.selectExpr("src as id").union(edges.selectExpr("dst as id")).distinct()

from graphframes import GraphFrame

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
```

As a test the in-degree of each vertex can be checked:

```python
g.inDegrees.show()
```

prints

```
+---+--------+
| id|inDegree|
+---+--------+
|  3|       5|
|  2|       2|
+---+--------+
```

This result is consistent with the given data: vertex `2` has two incoming edges from the first line of the example data and vertex `3` has three incoming edges from the second data line and two edges from the third line.